AbiEncodingBytesSizeMismatchError
I have a function selector like this function placeOrder(bytes32 _uuid, uint256 _recipient) public payable. While trying to integrate the frontend into the contract, I convert the string to a byte32 using ethers util encodeBytes32String. But I get the error AbiEncodingBytesSizeMismatchError
  const handlePayTransaction = async () => {
    if (payAmount.trim() === "" || accountNumber.trim() === "") {
      alert("Input fields cannot be empty");
      return;
    }
    
  
    try {
      if(isConnected){
        let uuid = encode;
        let formatted_amount = parseEther(payAmount);

        let format_number = Number(accountNumber)
        let {request, result} = await simulateContract(config,{
          address: "0x10846782C728a193102A7cf3a7c40E2071Ebc958",
          abi:[...PayAbi],
          functionName: "placeOrder",
          value:formatted_amount,
          args: [uuid, format_number],
        });
        const hash = await writeContract(config, request);
        console.log('hash:', hash)
      }else{
        console.error("not connected")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Transaction error:", error);
    }
  };

